# Angular sorting with nested array

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been trying to find an answer for a while and have been unable to do so.  I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to sort the following data (`members` property) within ng-repeat without using a third party tool.

```
$scope.element = {
    'sortOrder' : '[0].value' // <-- what is wrong? =[
    'members': [
        [
            { 'name' : 'a', 'value' : 'some' },
            { 'name' : 'b', 'value' : 'value' },
            { 'name' : 'c', 'value' : 'another' },
            { 'name' : 'd', 'value' : 'value' }
        ],
        [
            { 'name' : 'a', 'value' : 'other' },
            { 'name' : 'b', 'value' : 'stuff' },
            { 'name' : 'c', 'value' : 'cats' },
            { 'name' : 'd', 'value' : 'reddit' }
        ],
        [
            { 'name' : 'a', 'value' : 'internets' },
            { 'name' : 'b', 'value' : 'bigdata' },
            { 'name' : 'c', 'value' : 'winwin' },
            { 'name' : 'd', 'value' : 'himom' }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So, the above data is essentially representing a table.  The data can't be restructured for various reasons.  Right now I have the following as my markup:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="key in element.members[0]">
                <a href="#" ng-click="element.sortOrder = '[' + $index + ']' + '.value'">{{ key.name }}</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="subelement in element.members | orderBy : element.sortOrder">
            <td ng-repeat="element in subelement" ng-include src="template(element, true)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `sortOrder` property looks like... it could be correct?  I looked at other examples where people had to do this sort of thing (they were using named properties instead of indexes) and I thought I might be getting somewhere, but to no avail.

Any words of enlightenment would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `[0].value` with `orderBy`, the string used with `orderBy` should be a property of the objects you want to sort. In your case, you want to sort an array of arrays, but `[0].value` isn't a property of an array, so your approach doesn't work.

However, `orderBy` can take a "Getter" function to get a value from the object you're sorting, so you can utilize it as follow:

Controller:

```
$scope.element = {
    sortOrder: -1, // sortOrder is the index, -1 = unsorted
    members: [...]
};

$scope.getValue = function(member) {
    if ($scope.element.sortOrder < 0) {
        return null; // keep members being unsorted
    }
    return member[$scope.element.sortOrder].value;
};
```

Template:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="key in element.members[0]">
                <a href="#" ng-click="element.sortOrder = $index">{{ key.name }}</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="subelement in element.members | orderBy : getValue">
            <td ng-repeat="element in subelement" ng-include src="template(element, true)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is an working plunk for you to play with: http://plnkr.co/edit/bebYBCoa6zptOHNLVL9X

Comment: Thanks man, adding a custom sorting function was the way to go.  Wasn't aware of this!